# Why do I keep getting a "No suitable driver found" error?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

When I try to connect from GAE to Cloud SQL I get this error:

> "No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:google:mysql://parasql-app:inst101/db1384221549822"

My code looks like this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://" + this.instance_name + "/" + this.database_name);
```

I have no problems connecting with the older style "jdbc:google:rdbms://" connect string.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to enable mysql connector/j. Please follow the instruction from the link below.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j